# Best java Quicksort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

i've seen many quicksort algorithms and I'm wondering what the difference between these two are and if there are any more, perhaps simpler ones. Apart from the fact that one is for ints and the other for chars..

This is the first:

```
public class MyQuickSort {

private int array[];
private int length;

public void sort(int[] inputArr) {

    if (inputArr == null || inputArr.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    this.array = inputArr;
    length = inputArr.length;
    quickSort(0, length - 1);
}

private void quickSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {

    int i = lowerIndex;
    int j = higherIndex;
    // calculate pivot number, I am taking pivot as middle index number
    int pivot = array[lowerIndex+(higherIndex-lowerIndex)/2];
    // Divide into two arrays
    while (i <= j) {
        /**
         * In each iteration, we will identify a number from left side which
         * is greater then the pivot value, and also we will identify a number
         * from right side which is less then the pivot value. Once the search
         * is done, then we exchange both numbers.
         */
        while (array[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (array[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            exchangeNumbers(i, j);
            //move index to next position on both sides
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    // call quickSort() method recursively
    if (lowerIndex < j)
        quickSort(lowerIndex, j);
    if (i < higherIndex)
        quickSort(i, higherIndex);
}

private void exchangeNumbers(int i, int j) {
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

public static void main(String a[]){

    MyQuickSort sorter = new MyQuickSort();
    int[] input = {24,2,45,20,56,75,2,56,99,53,12};
    sorter.sort(input);
    for(int i:input){
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
  }
 }
```

And the second:

```
class Quicksort{
static void qsort(char items[]){
    qs(items, 0, items.length-1);
}

//a recursive version of Quicksort for characters
private static void qs(char items[], int left, int right){
    int i, j;
    char x, y;

    i = left; j = right;
    x = items[(left+right)/2];

    do{
        while((items[i] < x) && (i < right)) i++;
        while((x < items[j]) && (j > left)) j--;

        if(i <= j){
            y = items[i];
            items[i] = items[j];
            items[j] = y;
            i++; j--;
        }
    } while(i <= j);

    if(left < j) qs(items, left, j);
    if(i < right) qs(items, i, right);
 }
}

public class QSDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char a[] = { 'd', 'x', 'a', 'r', 'p', 'j', 'i' };
    int i;

    System.out.println("Original array: ");
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        System.out.print(a[i]);

    System.out.println();

    //now, sort the array
    Quicksort.qsort(a);

    System.out.println("Sorted array: ");
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        System.out.print(a[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: The best one is `Arrays.sort()`.  Take a look at the source code, it's pretty crazy.

Comment: These two are the same, except that one of them extracts the swap function and checks for boundary conditions.

Comment: @markspace it only uses quick sort for primitive types where the order doesn't matter otherwise it uses merge sort which is stable.

Answer (score 0):

How good quicksort performs depends mainly on the choice of pivots. If you choose them perfectly you have O(n log n) which is also the average case, but the worst case is O(n^2). So the implementation with the best strategy for choosing pivots will outperform the others for big arrays, but it might be an overhead for small arrays. What is a good strategy for choosing pivots? It depends on the problem and the data you expect. So to ask this would be similar to ask which is the "best" programming language and the answer is: it depends on the problem. If you are looking for really generalized approach then there are strategies that reduce the *probability* of poor pivot choices but they don't guarantee it. Or hybrids like [Introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort).